# How to create, but not overwrite, a file and manage its permissions with ansible?

Tags: ansible

The task seems simple. If the file does not exist, create it, otherwise retain the file and its content. In both cases, apply permissions (`owner`, `group`, `mode`).

The most obvious candidate to this task is `ansible.builtin.file` with `state: touch`. However, it always appears as changed as the times need to be updated. Rather, once it exists and modes are ok, it should just be ok.

The next candidate likely is `ansible.builtin.copy`. If passing `force: false`, it creates the file. However, it does not fix up permission on an already existing file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *The most obvious candidate to this task is `ansible.builtin.file` with `state: touch`.*

Right, this could be an option.

> *However, it always appears as changed as the times need to be updated.*

According the documentation [`file` module - Parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameters) not necessarily since `access_time` and `modification_time`

> *Should be `preserve` when no modification is required*

The following minimal example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Create file
    file:
      path: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test.file"
      owner: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      group: "users"
      access_time: preserve
      modification_time: preserve
      state: touch

  - name: Touch again
    file:
      path: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test.file"
      owner: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      group: "users"
      access_time: preserve
      modification_time: preserve
      state: touch
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Create file] ***************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Touch again] ***************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1
```